# Error using SMOTE TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64

Tags: python, resampling, smote, oversampling

I'm preparing an unbalanced dataset and would like to use a Python package called SMOTE. When I try to run the code it shows up an error: **TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64**

My dataset (first 5 rows):

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD1aN.png)

The error traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\integer.py in safe_cast(values, dtype, copy)
    147     try:
--> 148         return values.astype(dtype, casting="safe", copy=copy)
    149     except TypeError:

TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-456-c6d4d3314a06> in <module>
      5 
      6 # transform the dataset
----> 7 X_smote, y_smote = pipeline.fit_resample(X, y)
      8 
      9 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\pipeline.py in fit_resample(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    351         """
    352         last_step = self._final_estimator
--> 353         Xt, yt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    354         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    355                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    234                 )
    235             elif hasattr(cloned_transformer, "fit_resample"):
--> 236                 X, y, fitted_transformer = fit_resample_one_cached(
    237                     cloned_transformer, X, y,
    238                     message_clsname='Pipeline',

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 352         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\pipeline.py in _fit_resample_one(sampler, X, y, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    401                       **fit_params):
    402     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
--> 403         X_res, y_res = sampler.fit_resample(X, y, **fit_params)
    404 
    405         return X_res, y_res, sampler

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\base.py in fit_resample(self, X, y)
     86               if binarize_y else output[1])
     87 
---> 88         X_, y_ = arrays_transformer.transform(output[0], y_)
     89         return (X_, y_) if len(output) == 2 else (X_, y_, output[2])
     90 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\_validation.py in transform(self, X, y)
     38 
     39     def transform(self, X, y):
---> 40         X = self._transfrom_one(X, self.x_props)
     41         y = self._transfrom_one(y, self.y_props)
     42         return X, y

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\_validation.py in _transfrom_one(self, array, props)
     57             import pandas as pd
     58             ret = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=props["columns"])
---> 59             ret = ret.astype(props["dtypes"])
     60         elif type_ == "series":
     61             import pandas as pd

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5681                 if col_name in dtype:
   5682                     results.append(
-> 5683                         col.astype(dtype=dtype[col_name], copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5684                     )
   5685                 else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5696         else:
   5697             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5698             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5699             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5700 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    580 
    581     def astype(self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"):
--> 582         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    583 
    584     def convert(self, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, filter, **kwargs)
    440                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    441             else:
--> 442                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    443             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    444 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    623             vals1d = values.ravel()
    624             try:
--> 625                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
    626             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    627                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    819     # dispatch on extension dtype if needed
    820     if is_extension_array_dtype(dtype):
--> 821         return dtype.construct_array_type()._from_sequence(arr, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    822 
    823     if not isinstance(dtype, np.dtype):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\integer.py in _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype, copy)
    352     @classmethod
    353     def _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype=None, copy=False):
--> 354         return integer_array(scalars, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    355 
    356     @classmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\integer.py in integer_array(values, dtype, copy)
    133     TypeError if incompatible types
    134     """
--> 135     values, mask = coerce_to_array(values, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    136     return IntegerArray(values, mask)
    137 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\integer.py in coerce_to_array(values, dtype, mask, copy)
    249         values = safe_cast(values, dtype, copy=False)
    250     else:
--> 251         values = safe_cast(values, dtype, copy=False)
    252 
    253     return values, mask

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\integer.py in safe_cast(values, dtype, copy)
    153             return casted
    154 
--> 155         raise TypeError(
    156             f"cannot safely cast non-equivalent {values.dtype} to {np.dtype(dtype)}"
    157         )

TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64
```

```
X = new_dataset_enc.drop(['stroke'], axis=1)
 
y = new_dataset_enc['stroke']

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from collections import Counter

num_before = dict(Counter(y))

over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.8)

under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.8)

steps = [('o', over), ('u', under)]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)

# transform the dataset
X_smote, y_smote = pipeline.fit_resample(X, y)

# the numbers after SMOTE
num_after =dict(Counter(y_smote))
```

I have already tried several ways to fix it, but the issue keeps showing up. There are no "NaN" values in columns or missing ones. I've changed the type of each column to int64 and to object to test if that could fix the error. Nothing works.

Appreciate a lot any idea to come up with a solution.

Comment: WHERE does it show that error?  Please include the complete traceback.

Comment: Hi Tim! I already included the error traceback. Thank you!

Comment: That is not the whole traceback, that's just the end.  It still doesn't tell us which line caused the problem.  Do not include screenshots of code in StackOverflow -- always cut-and-paste the code itself.

Comment: Ok, now it is complete traceback in plain code text.

Comment: I would suggest `y = new_dataset_enc['stroke'].astype(np.float64)`

Comment: Hi Tim! I did what you suggested but it keeps yielding the same error! I'm trying some other things, let's see...I'll keep you updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue. my solution is similar with Tim's suggestion which is adding:
`y = y.astype(np.float64)`
but it's not enough for me since it return the same error.
It works when I also convert the x to float64 like:
`X = X.astype(np.float64)`

right after your first two code line